# How to create new DataFrame based on conditions from another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following DataFrame:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F    Cost 
0   1   1   0   0   0    10
0   0   1   0   1   0    3
1   0   0   0   0   1    5
0   1   0   1   0   0    7
```

I want to construct a new DataFrame based on the values above.

Specifically, if `value==1` then combine their columns into one and assign value for the new column from `Cost` column above.

So the expected output would be something like:

```
BC  CE  AF  BD    
10   3   5   7
```

How can I achieve such thing?

Comment: Please do not use images, as its makes it difficult to copy the data and also takes more bandwidth.

Comment: @quest sorry about that, I edited the question to avoid using images

Comment: No apologies needed :), I have learned the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try the [`dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) of the the binary columns with the column names to get the key string based on 1s and 0s, then add the `Cost` Column back:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['Cost'])
new_df = df[cols].dot(cols).to_frame(name='key')
new_df['Cost'] = df['Cost']
```

`new_df`:

```
  key  Cost
0  BC    10
1  CE     3
2  AF     5
3  BD     7
```

The DataFrame can be transposed if needed:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['Cost'])
new_df = df[cols].dot(cols).to_frame(name='key')
new_df['Cost'] = df['Cost']
new_df = new_df.set_index('key').T.rename_axis(columns=None)
```

`new_df`:

```
      BC  CE  AF  BD
Cost  10   3   5   7
```

---

DataFrame and imports:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": [0, 0, 1, 0],
    "B": [1, 0, 0, 1],
    "C": [1, 1, 0, 0],
    "D": [0, 0, 0, 1],
    "E": [0, 1, 0, 0],
    "F": [0, 0, 1, 0],
    "Cost": [10, 3, 5, 7],
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a loop to do it. With [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar), you can achieve it with `dplyr`-like syntax:

```py
>>> from datar.all import *
>>> 
>>> # Create the df
>>> df = tribble(
...     f.A,   f.B,   f.C,   f.D,   f.E,   f.F,    f.Cost,
...     0,     1,     1,     0,     0,     0,      10,
...     0,     0,     1,     0,     1,     0,      3,
...     1,     0,     0,     0,     0,     1,      5,
...     0,     1,     0,     1,     0,     0,      7,
... )
>>> df
        A       B       C       D       E       F    Cost
  <int64> <int64> <int64> <int64> <int64> <int64> <int64>
0       0       1       1       0       0       0      10
1       0       0       1       0       1       0       3
2       1       0       0       0       0       1       5
3       0       1       0       1       0       0       7
>>> # replace value with column names
>>> df = df >> mutate(across(f[1:6], lambda x: if_else(x, x.name, "")))  
>>> df
         A        B        C        D        E        F    Cost
  <object> <object> <object> <object> <object> <object> <int64>
0                 B        C                                 10
1                          C                 E                3
2        A                                            F       5
3                 B                 D                         7
>>> # unite the columns
>>> df = df >> unite('col', f[1:6], sep="") 
>>> df
       col    Cost
  <object> <int64>
0       BC      10
1       CE       3
2       AF       5
3       BD       7
>>> # reshape the result
>>> df >> column_to_rownames(f.col) >> t()
          BC      CE      AF      BD
     <int64> <int64> <int64> <int64>
Cost      10       3       5       7
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of the datar package.

Comment: Interesting! I did not know about `datar`.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I will proceed:

## Create the df

```
data = {
    "A": [0, 0, 1, 0],
    "B": [1, 0, 0, 1],
    "C": [1, 1, 0, 0],
    "D": [0, 0, 0, 1],
    "E": [0, 1, 0, 0],
    "F": [0, 0, 1, 0],
    "Cost": [10, 3, 5, 7],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

## Get the columns names

```
def make_df(row):
    row = row.to_dict()
    return "".join([k for k, v in row.items() if v if k!="Cost"])

df_ind = df.apply(make_df, axis=1)
```

## Create the desired data frame

```
pd.DataFrame(df.Cost.values, index=df_ind.values).T
```

This will give you:

```
 BC CE  AF  BD
 10 3   5   7
```

Answer (score 1):

Not as nice as previous answers, but straightforward & step-by-step:

```
outp_dict = {}

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    new_col = ""
    col_nr = 0
    for value in row:
        if value and row.index[col_nr] is not "Cost":
            new_col += str(row.index[col_nr])
        col_nr += 1
    outp_dict[new_col] = row[-1]

outp_df = pd.DataFrame(outp_dict, index = [0])
```

Comment: Thanks! It works on this specific example but did not show all possibilities in case of duplicate entries when values of A-F are the same but cost is different.